# React Native Unhandled JS Exception: Error

Tags: ios, react-native

I am starting a new react-native project and running into an issue - I am receiving an Unhandled JS Exception without the feedback I need to fix it.

I ran the CLI `react-native init TBCalc` command

I then ran `npm install`

Finally, I ran `react-native run-ios`

**Versions**

- React-native-cli: 2.0.1
- React-native: 0.41.2
- xcode 8.2.1

[Screenshot of Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiDHO.png)

Error in xcode console:

```
2017-02-16 12:09:25.253 TBCalc[88786:17379194] -[RCTJSStackFrame objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000053aa0
```

Comment: I have the same error :/

Comment: Seems related: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13299. No solutions yet :(